# Remove url segment in codeigniter with .htaccess

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I uploaded a Codeigniter project to /dev folder and the old url was `http://example.com/dev`. But now i moved the project to root folder. So the updated url is  `http://example.com`.  How can i redirect old url to new url by editing `.htaccess` file. Can i remove the url segment `/dev/`  from url like removing `index.php`

i tried this method by adding the below code to .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/dev/(.+)$ /$1 [L,QSA]
```

but didnt work

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure the base URL in the config is correct.

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://example.com/";
```

after that, you can try with .htaccess

change `RewriteRule ^/dev/(.+)$ /$1 [L,QSA]` to the following line.

> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dev/$1 [L]

Comment: I already tried this. but didnt working in codeigniter. I used RedirectMatch 301 /dev http://www.example.com

Comment: I have updated the answer please check with the base URL.

Answer (score 0):

use this as `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I think this removes /index.php from the url. i already had the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please add following code in your .htaccess file.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php


<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks. i will try this code. Now i temporarly redirected using,  RedirectMatch 301 /dev http://www.example.com

Comment: can you explain in brief?