# How to call many function with one controller file?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How to removed url index.php in codeigniter ?
My output display :- http://localhost/shukla/index.php/home/about
And i tried to get result display:- http://localhost/shukla/home/about
http://localhost/:server_name/shukla/:folder_name/index.php/home/about/:about_page

I create a `CodeIgniter`, `controller file--> Home.php`

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {


   public function index()
   {

       $this->load->view('template/header');
       $this->load->view('home');
       $this->load->view('template/footer');

   }
   public function about()
   {
       $this->load->view('template/header');
       $this->load->view('about');
       $this->load->view('template/footer');

   }
   public function contact()
   {
       $this->load->view('template/header');
       $this->load->view('contact');
       $this->load->view('template/footer');

   }

}
```

In view folder:  `home.php` , `about.php`, `contact.php`

```
config.php  set  base_url $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';
removed index.php :  $config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: set .htaccess file
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: plese visit this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57266556/remove-url-segment-in-codeigniter-with-htaccess/57269005#57269005

Answer (score 0):

In config.php there is an option "index_page" make it blank.

path : project_folder->application->config->config.php

change

`$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`

to

`$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: I tried but the output  reesult                                                                                           404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.

Comment: RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L] you can try this or also you can refer to CI documentation. Refer Link : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file